# Why is the assignment operator not called in this case in favor of the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

From the wikipedia page for copy constructors:

```
X a = X();     

// valid given X(const X& copy_from_me) but not valid given X(X& copy_from_me)
// because the second wants a non-const X&
// to create a, the compiler first creates a temporary by invoking the default constructor
// of X, then uses the copy constructor to initialize as a copy of that temporary. 
// For some compilers both versions actually work but this behaviour should not be relied 
// upon because it's non-standard.
```

Specifically the part:

> " the compiler first creates a temporary by invoking the default
>   constructor of X, then uses the copy constructor to initialize as a
>   copy of that temporary. "

My question is (assuming this is correct) why is this so?  From the code, I would guess that the compiler would use the assignment operator after constructing an X.

I'm guessing its because assignment takes place in the same expression as initialization?

Also, what would be the reason to use this formula, rather than just a normal initialization `X a;` or if you want to copy `X a(b);` ?

Comment: `T a = x;` is equivalent to `T a(T(x));`.

Comment: @GManNickG Aren't you only initializing x in the second statement?

Comment: well as everyone says, it's really the semantic definition of c++.  However, there is a reason for that.  Would you want to construct twice, then copy?  or would you want to construct twice with two potentially different constructors?  Which is more optimal?  Also, have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision.  The latest standard allows for some leeway.

Comment: @Raskol: I'm not sure I follow. In the second statement, a temporary `T` is constructed from `x`, and then `a` is copy-constructed from that temporary (hence the page saying the copy-constructor needs to be `const T&`, since temproaries don't bind to non-const lvalue references. In C++11 a non-const rvalue reference, `T&&`, would work as well; this is a move constructor). There is indeed no assignment. And since the first statement is exactly equivalent, the first has no assignment either.

Comment: @GManNickG Ah my mistake, yea I see it now, `T(x)` is creating a temporary T from x.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that since C++17 there is no copy-construction either; this syntax now means to default-construct an `X`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the code is **constructing** an object. The = sign here is initializing, not assigning. You can only assign to an existing object, not to one that's under construction.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a matter of understanding the grammar of C++. The statement `X a = X();` is a declaration statement with initializer, and *not* an assignment expression. The grammatical meaning of this statement is to declare a variable `a` of type `X` and copy-initialize it from the expression `X()`. There is no assign­ment involved here in any way.