# conversion operator (assignment operator=) is not responding

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I've been trying to test a  call to an assignment operator= for my struct:

```
struct array{

    void* data;

    template<typename S, typename T>
    array& operator= (const map<S, T>& that){ cout << "worked...";  return *this;}

   private:
     array();           //i don't need this
};
```

and I test-drove like this:

```
map<int, string> var;
array arr = var;
```

I received an error:

```
Error: conversion from
'std::map<int, string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, string> > >'
to non-scalar type 'array' requested*/
```

Question:
what exactly is the problem? How do I overload such an operator? I mean 
`operator=`, which should convert an object of a different type, into its own class type.

Comment: Please don't label C++ code blocks as Javascript code snippets - they really can't be run in the browser...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the assignment operator not called in this case in favor of the copy constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637805/why-is-the-assignment-operator-not-called-in-this-case-in-favor-of-the-copy-cons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration

```
map<int, string> var;
array arr = var;
```

… doesn't invoke the copy assignment operator.

It uses (or behaves as if it uses) the copy constructor: in the declaration `=` denotes copy initialization.

If the class had had other constructors they would have been considered for converting `var` to an `array` instance, that would then (unless this part was optimized away) be passed to the copy constructor.

But you only have the default copy constructor.

---

Conversion from a type B to a class type A is best expressed in one of two ways:

- via a class A constructor that accepts a B.
- if B is a class, via a B `operator A` (a conversion operator).

---

In other news:

- `void*` is a way to discard type information. Discarding type information is a way to create trouble. So, `void*` is best a-voided.

Comment: well articulated @Cheers and hth. - Alf. thanks for the info. maybe i should have a rethink.

Comment: Sorry, I had to deal with some garbage (they collect it about this time) so I forgot to add to complete the part of copy initialization. Fixing that now.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the only explanation for why my `Var x = 1.0;` wouldn't work with assignment overloading! Only `Var x; x = 1.0;` worked! Makes sense now

Comment: Adding to this see https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/9-14-overloading-the-assignment-operator/ `The assignment operator (operator=) is used to copy values from one object to another already existing object.`